# Query runs on PL/SQL but doesn't run on ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, plsql

so I have this query in SL/SQL :

```
DECLARE
UNI VARCHAR(250);
NI VARCHAR(250);
NOME VARCHAR(250);
POSTOO VARCHAR(250);
FINALMENTE VARCHAR(250);
BEGIN
SELECT UNIDADE INTO UNI FROM OWNDB2.T_UNIDADES WHERE SIGUNIDADE = 'DAGI';                                            
SELECT NII INTO NI FROM OWNDB2.T_UNID_CARGO WHERE UNIDADE = UNI AND DETALHE = 'C00';                                            
select NOME INTO NOME from owndb2.t_BASEPES where nii = NI;
select POSTO INTO POSTOO from owndb2.t_BASEPES where nii = NI;
select DESPOSTO INTO FINALMENTE from owndb2.t_CODPOSTO where POSTO = POSTOO;
END;
```

I run this query in PL/SQL and it gives me what I want to see but when I paste this query in Asp.net C# it just gives a error saying that the query as an incorrect syntax.
And yes, the Database that I am connecting to, is an Oracle DataBase, that query is litterly the tables of the Database that I am using in my ASP.Net project.

This is the way that I put the query in ASP.Net :

```
"DECLARE" +
"UNI VARCHAR(250);" +
"NI VARCHAR(250);" +
"NOME VARCHAR(250);" +
"POSTOO VARCHAR(250);" +
"FINALMENTE VARCHAR(250);" +
"BEGIN" +
"SELECT UNIDADE INTO UNI FROM OWNDB2.T_UNIDADES WHERE SIGUNIDADE = 'DAGI';" +                                           
"SELECT NII INTO NI FROM OWNDB2.T_UNID_CARGO WHERE UNIDADE = UNI AND DETALHE = 'C00';" +                                          
"SELECT NOME INTO NOME from owndb2.t_BASEPES where nii = NI;" +
"SELECT POSTO INTO POSTOO from owndb2.t_BASEPES where nii = NI;" +
"SELECT DESPOSTO INTO FINALMENTE from owndb2.t_CODPOSTO where POSTO = POSTOO;" +
"END;"
```

Why is the query running well in PL/SQL and in ASP.Net just gives me an incorrect syntax error ?

PS : I am just inserting the query because it's what I am having problems with, I am not inserting all the Sqlconnections and sql commands behind it, but the query is my problem, I hope that you guys understand it.

Comment: Look at the spaces and you'll see. Right now your query looks like `DECLAREUNI VARCHAR(250);NI VARCHAR(250); ... POSTOO;END;`

Comment: *"And yes, the Database that I am connecting to, is an Oracle DataBase"* - then why do you add SQL Server tag?

Comment: What output do you expect to receive? It appears to populate some local variables, then ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL statement in your C# code lacks of spaces. 
Right now your query looks like `DECLAREUNI VARCHAR(250);NI VARCHAR(250); ... POSTOO;END;`.

```
"DECLARE" +
" UNI VARCHAR(250);" +
" NI VARCHAR(250);" +
" NOME VARCHAR(250);" +
" POSTOO VARCHAR(250);" +
" FINALMENTE VARCHAR(250);" +
" BEGIN" +
" SELECT UNIDADE INTO UNI FROM OWNDB2.T_UNIDADES WHERE SIGUNIDADE = 'DAGI';" +                                           
" SELECT NII INTO NI FROM OWNDB2.T_UNID_CARGO WHERE UNIDADE = UNI AND DETALHE = 'C00';" +                                          
" SELECT NOME INTO NOME from owndb2.t_BASEPES where nii = NI;" +
" SELECT POSTO INTO POSTOO from owndb2.t_BASEPES where nii = NI;" +
" SELECT DESPOSTO INTO FINALMENTE from owndb2.t_CODPOSTO where POSTO = POSTOO;" +
" END;"
```

should do the trick or simply put it into one long [string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) via `@"string"`:

```
string query = @"DECLARE
UNI VARCHAR(250);
NI VARCHAR(250);
NOME VARCHAR(250);
POSTOO VARCHAR(250);
FINALMENTE VARCHAR(250);
BEGIN
SELECT UNIDADE INTO UNI FROM OWNDB2.T_UNIDADES WHERE SIGUNIDADE = 'DAGI';                                            
SELECT NII INTO NI FROM OWNDB2.T_UNID_CARGO WHERE UNIDADE = UNI AND DETALHE = 'C00';                                            
select NOME INTO NOME from owndb2.t_BASEPES where nii = NI;
select POSTO INTO POSTOO from owndb2.t_BASEPES where nii = NI;
select DESPOSTO INTO FINALMENTE from owndb2.t_CODPOSTO where POSTO = POSTOO;
END;"
```

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and keep you guys updated about it !